# R: difference between [[ ]] and $ while building linear model

Tags: r, linear-regression

I was building a model using `lm()` and put this in a self-defined function to compute the RSS of the model.

but I noticed that it's different between `$` and `[[ ]]` to assign response variables:

model1:

```
mymodel1 <- lm(df$resp.var ~., data = df)
summary(mymodel1)
```

model2:

```
mymodel2 <- lm(df[["resp.var"]] ~., data = df)
summary(mymodel2)
```

A warning message will pop up after the `summary()` clause is submitted:

```
Warning message:
In summary.lm(mymodel2) : essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable
```

When I checked the coefficients, the response variable (`resp.var`) was taken as one of the predictors in the 2nd model.

And I got the same message when I change the model to (in the dataset, the response variable is in the 1st column):

```
mymodel3 <- lm(df[,1] ~., data = df)
summary(mymodel3)
```

I also tried directly passing the `resp.var` in the `lm()`:

```
model4 <- lm(resp.var ~., data = df)
summary(mymodel4)
```

and I got this message:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = resp.var ~ ., data = df, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'xxxx')
```

But I can make sure that the lengths are aligned...

Since resp.var is a parameter of the self-defined function

```
selfun <- function(pred.var, resp.var){
  ...
}
```

I want to use the parameter `resp.var` directly in the model inside the function, is there a way to realize that? or did I made mistake?

Comment: since you specify `data=df` you can just type `rep.var~.`

Comment: In your example, you use `resp.var` and `rep.var` and get different results. Simple typo when entering in StackOverflwo? Or are you encountering the difference between two variables?

Comment: Hi @Thomas , it's a typo I commited in the question block. I've corrected it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You only need to pass the name of the columns to the `formula` argument of `lm`, not vectors of data. Simply using `resp.var ~ .` will get you what you need.

If `resp_var` is a variable containing a string with the name of the response variable, the best way is to use `as.formula`:

```
lm(as.formula(sprintf('%s ~ .', resp_var)), data = df)
```

Comment: Hi @Paul Hiemstra , the `as.formula` helps! But I still don't get the point, the parameter `resp` is exactly the name of response variable, why I need use `as.formula(sprintf())` instead of directly passing the `resp` to the formula like `lm(resp ~., data = df)` (which I tried before (leading to another error message) and forgot to put in the question block)?

Comment: If you response variable is always called `resp`, there is no need to pass it to the function. Simply use `lm(resp ~ ., data = df)`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not to passs directly the formula ?

```
selfun <- function(form,data){
  lm(form,data=data)
}
```

Then you simply call it :

```
selfun(resp.var~pred.var,data=df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `df[['resp.var']]` and `df$resp.var` return the same vector. That is how the `$`-function is defined. If I read your question correctly you want `df[[resp.var]]`, since it sounds like the value of resp.var is the column name. You want 'resp.var' to be evaluated.

If you got "another error message" as you mentioned in your comment to Paul, then you need to post the output from str(df) and the full text of the error message.

The warning message about exact fit has nothing to do with any of this. If you get an exact prediction, `summary.lm` gives a warning, but without the data we cannot see what might be happening.